# Teamviewer-who can see me?

Tags: privacy

Here at my school teamviewer was installed in all faculty computers. My question is, when I access another teacher's computer via teamviewer, are they able to see that I am doing so? Can they see and be aware that I am seeing whatever they are doing on their computer?

Comment: AFAIK, In the default configuration, TeamViewer requests the permission of the local user before a remote user can control or even view their desktop.

Comment: @Philipp This is not the case if you install the TeamViewer background daemon service.

Answer (score 3):

When you connect to another computer with Team Viewer, a window appears in the bottom right hand corner of that users screen showing the connection. There are buttons for them to activate video, audio, chat, file transfer, or close the connection. If they are set up to allow you to connect (you need their ID), you will be in control of their computer, so your presence will be completely obvious.

Even if you use it successfully while they are away, TeamViewer logs incoming connections, so there will be record of it.

Probably a good idea to just **not do it** unless you're supposed to.

Comment: Thanks, I am supposed to, however I was under the impression that the person would be unaware. Thank you very much for your quick response.